# How to get bluetooth to work?

Tags: release-freya, live-cd, touchpad

I am using LiveUSB to see if Elementary works. After locating a mouse, and now able to navigate the OS, I proceeded to bluetooth settings. My trackpad, Apple brand, will briefly flash off and on about every 5 seconds. So I know it can see the device at moments, but it refuses to connect. It is the only active bluetooth atm. Hopefully you can get to work.
I like what I see but once I return the mouse to the owning computer, Elementary just becomes a picture to look at.
 PS liveusb problem solved by using computer port,NOT keyboard port.
Hardware: mac-mini late 2009, freya: 64bit

Comment: please mark the question as solving.

Answer (score 2):

Try to connect devices by "bluetooth settings" (not just klicking "Connect" in the top bar - this will make it appear to connect but it doesn't connect). Google the "pin option" for your devices, I think it is 0000 but I am not sure.
This way I have connected magic mouse, track pad, and apple wireless keyboard on a pc usually being a hackintosh. Just the mouse gives me still trouble, see "Magic mouse connection issues on PC"
Hope that helps

Comment: Thank you Florian! a little patience needed but 0000 did work, it flashed off on at slower rate, held device next to computer, had to input 0000 several times, but I am now using liveusb to answer you on a working system.
And bless you for taking time to answer, I found that a rare thing. I normally
spend time debugging or just abandonment.

Comment: Hi Pheonix, since you are an apple hardware user and since I still have that problem with the magic mouse disconnecting, please inform me if you stumble upon a hint to fix that. And if you have an idea to get a proper apple keyboard layout installed let me know as well. And please vote my answer up (the arrow up) In the meta page of this elementary os stack exchange they mention that this is somehow important...? Thanks